# load file to applet using Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I'm developing a sort of WebApp (it's an homework) using JS & Applet. The idea of the app is that: 
The user load a file and a private key. 
The system (client side) hash and sign the file (using RSA algorithm).
The hashedSigned File is passed to the Server (and stored).

The hashing and signing phase is accomplished by an Applet.

My problem is that the RSAPrivateKey is stored in the PC and I don't know how to load it. In Java the key is read/write using ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream but in Javascript I don't how to handle it. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: *"..but in Javascript I don't how to handle it."*  I dread the day when JS can load files off my local file-system.  A trusted applet can load files, or an applet deployed using JWS.

Comment: The applet should be not visible to the user. The file is load using the <input> tag of html and JS onLoad() event invoke a method (say doSignature(file,key) ) of the applet passing the key and the file just loaded. The problem is the way JS read the key that as I said is  previously saved using ObjectOutputStream. [My english is not so good, I don't know if you can understand what I'm trying to say]